# jquery retrieve css style set directly on element

Tags: jquery, css

How can I use jQuery to determine whether an element has a certain style set inline.

E.g, given the document

```
<style>
.MyClass { position: relative }
</style>
...
<div class="MyClass" id="div1" style="position: absolute"/>
<div class="MyClass" id="div2"/>
...
<script>
function f() {
    assert($('#div1').SOMETHING('position') == 'absolute');
    assert($('#div2').SOMETHING('position') == '');
}
</script>
```

If I use .css('position'), div2 is reported as being 'relative'. How can I determine which styles have actually been set inline?

Comment: if `css('position')` says relative, then that's because it is set to relative with your CSS class MyClass... div1, however should be reported as "absolute".

Comment: @peirix: I know, and the rendering is correct. However, I want to know whether I've set it inline. And sometimes I set position: relative inline as well, so I need to distinguish all these cases.

Comment: Oh. So what you're asking is if there is a way to know wether a certain style is set inline or using CSS markup? In which case I don't really think there is, except checking its style attribute as TTG suggests below, and parsing it for information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing

```
assert($('#div2').get(0).style.position == 'relative');
```

but I was hoping for a more jQueryish way of doing it.

Comment: You could put this code into the custom selector as desribed in my answer below

Comment: I could, but it wouldn't help me. My problem is "given this element, is its position set to relative?", but making the custom selector would solve the problem "Given these objects, which of them have their position set to relative?". That could also be a problem which someone need to solve, but not me, at least not now.

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own custom selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
        positionAbsolute: positionAbsolute,
    });
});

function positionAbsolute(el) {
    return $(el).css("position").indexOf("absolute") >= 0;
}
```

And then access this like so

```
if ($("#MyDiv").is(":positionAbsolute")){
    alert("Position absolute");
}
```

Does the style have to be inline? If you declared it in a CSS class, e.g,

```
.positionAbsolute{position: absolute}
```

and then you could use a class selctor instead:

```
if ($("#MyDiv").is(".positionAbsolute")){
    alert("Position absolute");
}
```

Comment: +1. Not because it solved my problem, but because it's a really cool thing to do. However, For the reason stated in the question I can not use .css('position')

Comment: Just got a down vote, and no explanation. That really irritates me (not the down vote, but the lack of explanation).

Answer (score 1):

what about `.attr('style')`?
And here's [a link](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr) to the jQuery docs.

Comment: just remember that if you use `attr('style')` you get "position:relative" in return and every other inline style as well...

Comment: I could do that, but then I'd have to parse the returned string. I'm going to set more styles than the position inline.

Answer (score -1):

Well you could just use the .css method, this returns all of the styles attached to that element.

Comment: I stated in the question why I could not do that.